# Dynamically creating jQuery listview in PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I would like to populate a jQuery listview in a PHP loop, and I attempted to do so by echoing javascript code that populates the list with a PHP variable. This is what I'm working with:

My HTML

```
<div data-role='page' id='feedPage'>
     <div data-role='content'>
        <ul id='pics' data-role='listview'>
        <li>test</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

and my PHP / JavaScript

```
echo "<script type='javascript'>
var pics = \$('#pics')
var pitem = \$('<li/>').html($myArray[element])
var plink = \$('<a/>')
pitem.append(plink)
pics.append(pitem)
pics.listview('refresh')
</script>";
```

but the list comes up blank. This code is running inside of a PHP `for` loop, and I am able to access and manipulate all the elements of `$myArray` just fine in PHP, but I cannot seem to populate the list. I even tried running this code with a simple `.html('hello')` to no avail. All I get is a blank list with the exception of the `test` item I hardcoded in the HTML. Is there a way to generate a list in PHP like  this, and if so, how can I do it properly?

Thanks!

SOLUTION:

I got this working simply by doing `<script type='text/javascript'>` and `.html('$myArray[element]')` (notice the single quotes). This works because the javascript is running inside a PHP echo. Oh, and none of my $ needed to be escaped. Final code:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
var pics = $('#pics')
var pitem = $('<li/>').html('$myArray[element]')
var plink = $('<a/>')
pitem.append(plink)
pics.append(pitem)
pics.listview('refresh')
</script>";
```

Comment: it's bad idea. You must you js files for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is in `type='javascript'`, it should be `type='text/javascript'`.

Another thing to consider is that the content of the `$myArray[element]` needs to be printed as a javascript string. Running `$myArray = array_map('json_encode', $myArray);` should do the trick.

Comment: The `type='text/javascript'` got it working for me! For the PHP variables I didn't need to do anything too special. I added my solution to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put your JS-code into `document.ready` event callback

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  var pics = $('#pics')
  var pitem = $('<li/>').html($myArray[element])
  var plink = $('<a/>')
  pitem.append(plink)
  pics.append(pitem)
  pics.listview('refresh')
});
```